# Paper orientaion is being changed in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm using .net 2012 with crystal reports 13.0.5 in both develop and production machines. **in one report only** of my application's reports, i'm getting paper orientation is being changed from portrait to landscape. **This occur only in production machine !!**

in design time, i have set orientation to portrait and even i include :

```
report.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Portrait;
```

but always i have got same result.

could anyone tell me what's going on ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is when you are setting it.

Comment: Thanks heringer,
usually i dont need to set orientation at run-time but i did it here  for reconfirmation that orientation is portrait.